# How do I display a logged in user's images from the database?

Tags: php, mysqli

Say if a user uploaded multiple images to their profile page, how would I display that specific user's images? I tried I did something like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<a href='profiles/uploads/".$row['image']."> ";
                echo "<img  id='img_div' title='".$row['image']."' alt='".$row['image']."'  src='profiles/uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
                //echo "<p id='img_div'>".$row['desc']."</p>";
                echo "</a>";
```

But I feel like this is terribly wrong because it is showing everyone's images and not the user's images. I tried looking up answers, but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You need to set user in sql query like `id = 10`.

And also missing `'` last of this line: `echo "<a href='profiles/uploads/".$row['image'].">";`

```
<?php
$user_id = 10;
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ". $user_id ." LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<a href='profiles/uploads/". $row['image'] ."'>";
    echo "<img id='img_div' title='".$row['image']."' alt='".$row['image']."' src='profiles/uploads/".$row['quotes']."'/>";
    //echo "<p id='img_div'>".$row['desc']."</p>";
    echo "</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! @ChandraKumar

Answer (score 1):

You need a where clause. `where id = 5`, of course, replace the number with whatever user you are looking for.

Right now the query `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC` is saying:

Select all columns from all users, ordering them by id.

Instead, you want something like:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {user id}` which states:

Select all columns from all users, where the id equals the user id.

As an aside, I'm not sure how you are setting up your database, but

> if a user uploaded multiple images to their profile page, how would I display that specific user's images

makes me think that you should really be having separate tables, if you want to allow multiple pictures.

Comment: so can I say `WHERE id = '$user_id'`  or something like that?

Comment: @AshleyHoward yes exactly

Comment: What if I go to another person's profile page, would I do the same thing or do that plus `AND username = '$username'`? @Matthew

Comment: If you are looking at another users profile page, I'm assuming that `$user_id` will be the id of that user, in which case you can do the same thing

Comment: yeah I was told to do a different table with username and user images.